# NSScanner issue with finding numbers that begin with 0

Tags: ios, swift, nsscanner

I having an issue using NSScanner.

I have this string:
195 058 042 yuiyui 123

and I'm trying to just return the integers. however, any number that contains a 0 before the space doesn't get scanned property.

```
 var note = "195 048 042 yuiyui 123"

let whitespaceAndPunctuationSet = NSMutableCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
let numbersCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()

let stringScanner = NSScanner(string: note)

var value = 0
while stringScanner.scanInteger(&value) {
    print(value)
}
```

and this prints the following:
195
48
42

It it missing the 0 from '048'
But I'm not sure why

it should print the following

195
048
42

Thanks

Comment: Integers don't have leading 0's, you can't scan it as an integer if you want to preserve that

Comment: Just try `let n = 000042 ; print(n)` , or enter "0 0 0 0 4 2" on your calculator :)

Comment: ah ok. that makes sense. So i guess i'll have to scan as a String right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture *numeric substrings* insider the longer string, `NSRegularExpression` is more appropriate:

```
let note = "195 048 042 yuiyui 123"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d+", options: [])

regex.enumerateMatchesInString(note, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, note.characters.count)) { result, flag, stop in
    guard let match = result else {
        // result is nil
        return
    }

    let range = match.rangeAtIndex(0)
    print((note as NSString).substringWithRange(range))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is perfect!